# Hadoop erreur connection refused when launched spark job : Call From namenode/192.168.64.9 to "name of my PC":42319 Connection refused

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I have a probleme with my cluster Hadoop, the error is as follow :

```
Call From namenode/192.168.64.9 to "name of my PC":42319 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

my cluster hadoop works fine. when I start-all.sh and jps I can see my namenode ressource manager datanodes working fine, I can connect to hdfs from every datanode everything works fine.

But when I try to executed a spark job exemple i get the error : connection refused.

/etc/hosts :

```
192.168.64.9 namenode.socal.rr.com
192.168.64.6 datanode1.socal.rr.com
192.168.64.7 datanode2.socal.rr.com
192.168.64.8 datanode3.socal.rr.com
```

jps -- datanodes :

```
9474 Jps
5191 DataNode
5337 NodeManager
5914 HistoryServer
```

jps -- namenodes

```
10352 HistoryServer
9426 ResourceManager
9206 SecondaryNameNode
8969 NameNode
15388 Jps
```

cat hadoop/etc/hadoop/workers

```
192.168.64.6
192.168.64.7
192.168.64.8
```

cat hadoop/etc/hadoop/masters

```
192.168.64.9
```

hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.64.9:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml :

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
       <value>192.168.64.9</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
       <value>192.168.64.9:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
       <value>192.168.64.9:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
       <value>1536</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
       <value>1536</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
       <value>128</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
       <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

the port generated in the error log -->

```
netstat -tnlpa | grep 43783
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5162/java
```

why is he calling this port?
Can you help me this error plzz